# How to automate labels on stacked bar chart

Tags: r

I'm having a couple of issues with a stack bar chart. One I would like to automate the data labels.I've given it a try, but it needs some tweaking. The second issue is that I would like to reverse the order of the years in the graph so that 2022 is on top.
counts<- structure(list(

```
 A = c(207,70), 
 B = c(212,75),
 C = c(207,73),
 D = c(206,73),
 E = c(197,69), 
 F = c(191,66),
 G = c(201,70)),


  .Names = c("2022",
         "2021",
         "2020",
         "2019",
         "2018",
         "2017",
         "2016"
         
), 
class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L)) #4L=number of numbers in each letter vector#

attach(counts)
print(counts)


# barplot
colors <- c("slategray3","dodgerblue4")
xFun <- function(x) x/2 + c(0, cumsum(x)[-length(x)])
par(mar=c(0, 6, 1, 30) + 0.1) # this sets margins to allow long labels
byc <- barplot(as.matrix(counts), horiz=TRUE, col=colors, 
           border=FALSE, las=1, xaxt='n',
           ylim = range(0, 10), xlim = range(-10, 100),
           width = .8)
# labels
labs <- data.frame(x=as.vector(sapply(counts, xFun)),  # apply `xFun` here 
               y=rep(byc, each=nrow(counts)),  # use `byc` here
               labels=as.vector(apply(counts, 1:2, paste0)), 
               stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

invisible(sapply(seq(nrow(labs)), function(x)  # `invisible` prevents unneeded 
console output
text(x=labs[x, 1:2], labels=labs[x, 1], cex=.9, font=2, col=0)))


# legend  (set `xpd=TRUE` to plot beyond margins!)
legend(2,7.5,  legend=c("Mean time to identify","Mean time to contain"),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
   fill=colors, horiz = T, bty='n', xpd=T, border = F)`
```